# React, a modal data only renders properly on second opening

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react modal, which has a group of checkboxes. Those checkboxes "checked" value comes from an API call. But the problem is, that they only get updated on the second click.

I have tried to set a condition to wait for the fetch of the data before loading the group of checkboxes. So mi app looks like this

In my parent component where I load my data

I have set a permUpdated state, which equals to false, but once the data is loaded, i set it to true

```
getPermissionsValue() {

    API.get('/user/' + this.state.rowId + '/permission')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                permissionValue: response.data,
                permUpdated: true
            }, () => {

                // console.log(this.state.permissionValue)
           });

        })
}
```

That state is passed as a prop to the child component which is the modal

```
<EditUserModal permUpdated={this.state.permUpdated} ....>
```

And in the childs render, I used to have this, and it worked properly but with doesnt get updated

```
 <div className="checkboxesIn">
         {permissionsPrint}    
 </div>
```

`{permissionsPrint}` are the checkboxes that I want to render. So ive set it like:

```
 <div className="checkboxesIn">
   {this.props.permUpdated ? {permissionsPrint} : null}
</div>
```

But that way my app crashes.

> ×
>   Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {permissionsPrint}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

This is how permissionPrint looks

```
    (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
2: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
3: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
4: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "div", key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This is how i create it

```
 var permissionsPrint = [];
        var valuesData = []
        this.props.permissionValue.map(e => valuesData = Object.entries(e))
        console.log(valuesData)
        for (let i = 1; i < valuesData.length; i++) {
            //console.log(valuesData[i][0])  //name of the permission
            //console.log(valuesData[i][1]) //true false
            permissionsPrint.push(<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id={valuesData[i][0]} value={valuesData[i][1]} defaultChecked={valuesData[i][1]} onChange={this.props.handleChangePermissions} />
                <label class="form-check-label" for={"inlineCheckbox" + i} style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{valuesData[i][0]}</label>
            </div>)
```

EDIT: Whole code of the modal

```
class EditUserModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userId: ""
    };
    console.log("PROOPPSS");
    console.log(props);
    console.log(this.props.permUpdated);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      email: this.props.email
    });
  }

  render() {
    var permissionsPrint = [];
    var valuesData = [];
    this.props.permissionValue.map(e => (valuesData = Object.entries(e)));
    console.log(valuesData);
    for (let i = 1; i < valuesData.length; i++) {
      //console.log(valuesData[i][0])  //name of the permission
      //console.log(valuesData[i][1]) //true false
      permissionsPrint.push(
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            id={valuesData[i][0]}
            value={valuesData[i][1]}
            defaultChecked={valuesData[i][1]}
            onChange={this.props.handleChangePermissions}
          />
          <label
            class="form-check-label"
            for={"inlineCheckbox" + i}
            style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
          >
            {valuesData[i][0]}
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    }
    console.log("this is THE PROP OF PERMUPDATED");
    console.log(this.props.permUpdated);
    if (!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="modalBg">
        <div className="flex-container">
          <div id="open-modal" className="modal-window">
            <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
              <div>
                {/* <p>{this.props.userId}</p>   */}
                <FontAwesomeIcon
                  className="closeIcon"
                  onClick={this.props.close}
                  icon={faTimesCircle}
                />

                <br></br>
                {this.props.userDataUpdated ? (
                  <Alert
                    className="alertEditUser"
                    variant="success"
                    dismissible
                    onClose={this.props.handleDismiss}
                  >
                    User Data Updated
                  </Alert>
                ) : null}
                {this.props.passwordMatchFailure ? (
                  <Alert
                    className="alertEditUser"
                    variant="danger"
                    dismissible
                    onClose={this.props.handleDismiss}
                  >
                    Passwords do not match
                  </Alert>
                ) : null}
                {this.props.emailCantBeBlank ? (
                  <Alert
                    className="alertEditUser"
                    variant="danger"
                    dismissible
                    onClose={this.props.handleDismiss}
                  >
                    Email Cant Be Blank
                  </Alert>
                ) : null}
                <div class="form-group emailgroup">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">
                    Change Email Address
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="name@example.com"
                    value={this.props.email}
                    onChange={this.props.handleChangeMail}
                  />
                </div>
                {/* <div class="form-group emailgroup">
                              <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Old Password</label>
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" />
                          </div> */}
                <div class="form-group emailgroup">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">New Password</label>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Input new password"
                    onChange={this.props.handleChangePass}
                  />
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Confirm new password"
                    onChange={this.props.handleChangePass2}
                    style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group emailgroup">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">User Permissions</label>
                  <br></br>
                  <div className="checkboxes">
                    <div className="checkboxesIn">
                      {/* {permissionsPrint}  */}
                      {this.props.permUpdated ? permissionsPrint : null}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">
                    Update
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default EditUserModal;
```

Whole code of the admin

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import API from "../services/axiosObject.js";
import "./css/Admin.css";
import Reactable from "reactable";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faEdit } from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons";
import EditUserModal from "./EditUserModal";
export default class Admin extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      retracted: false,
      userList: [],
      showModal: false,
      rowId: "",
      selectedMail: "",
      password: "",
      password2: "",
      userDataUpdated: false,
      passwordMatchFailure: false,
      emailCantBeBlank: false,
      permissionValue: [],
      permUpdated: false
    };
    this.getUserList = this.getUserList.bind(this);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeMail = this.handleChangeMail.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePass = this.handleChangePass.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleDismiss = this.handleDismiss.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePermissions = this.handleChangePermissions.bind(this);
    this.getPermissionsValue = this.getPermissionsValue.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserList();
  }

  handleChangeMail = evt => {
    this.setState({
      selectedMail: evt.target.value
    });
  };

  handleChangePass = evt => {
    this.setState({
      password: evt.target.value
    });
  };

  handleChangePass2 = evt => {
    this.setState({
      password2: evt.target.value
    });
  };

  handleChangePermissions = evt => {
    console.log(this.state.permissionValue);
    console.log("id: " + evt.target.id);
    var idu = evt.target.id;
    var checked = evt.target.checked;
    console.log("checked: " + evt.target.checked);

    var data = this.state.permissionValue[0];
    console.log("data1");
    console.log(data);
    data[idu] = checked;
    console.log("data2");
    console.log(data);

    this.setState({
      permissionValue: [data]
    });
  };

  getUserList() {
    API.get("/userlist").then(response => {
      this.setState(
        {
          userList: response.data
        },
        () => {
          console.log(this.state.userList);
        }
      );
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //console.log("updating")
    //console.log("email: " + this.state.selectedMail)
    var email = this.state.selectedMail;
    var password = this.state.password;
    var password2 = this.state.password2;
    var permissionValue = this.state.permissionValue;
    console.log("....");
    console.log("password: " + this.state.password);
    console.log("password2: " + this.state.password2);
    console.log("....");
    console.log("userId: " + this.state.rowId);
    console.log("email: " + email);

    if (password2 != password || email == "") {
      console.log("P2: " + password2);
      console.log("P1: " + password);

      if (password2 != password) {
        console.log("CONTRASEÑAS DISTINTAS");
        this.setState({
          passwordMatchFailure: true
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          emailCantBeBlank: true
        });
      }
    } else {
      console.log("ENTRA EN EL ELSE");
      if (password == undefined || password2 == undefined) {
        password = "";
        password2 = "";
      }
      API.post("/user/update/" + this.state.rowId, {
        email,
        password,
        permissionValue
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(permissionValue);
        if (response.data == "user data updated") {
          this.setState(
            {
              userDataUpdated: true
            },
            () => {
              console.log(this.state.userDataUpdated);
            }
          );
        }
      });
    }
  }

  handleDismiss() {
    console.log("HANDLING DISMISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
    this.setState({
      userDataUpdated: false,
      passwordMatchFailure: false,
      emailCantBeBlank: false
    });
  }

  showModal(rowId, rowEmail) {
    this.setState(
      {
        showModal: true,
        rowId: rowId,
        selectedMail: rowEmail
      },
      () => {
        this.getPermissionsValue();
      }
    );
  }

  closeModal() {
    console.log("CLOOOOOOSSSSINNGGGGGGGGGGGGG");
    this.setState(
      {
        showModal: false
      },
      () => {
        // console.log("clicked closeModal")
        // console.log(this.state.showModal)
      }
    );
  }

  getPermissionsValue() {
    API.get("/user/" + this.state.rowId + "/permission").then(response => {
      this.setState(
        {
          permissionValue: response.data,
          permUpdated: true
        },
        () => {}
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    var users = this.state.userList;

    const Table = Reactable.Table,
      Td = Reactable.Td,
      Tr = Reactable.Tr;

    if (users.length === 0) {
      return <p>loading</p>;
    }

    return (
      <div class="maincontainer">
        <div className="content-landing">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary "
            style={{ float: "right", marginRight: "20px" }}
            onClick={() => this.props.history.push("/register")}
          >
            New user
          </button>

          <Table
            className="table"
            filterable={["Email"]}
            itemsPerPage={8}
            currentPage={0}
            sortable={true}
          >
            {users.map(row => {
              return (
                <Tr className={row.className}>
                  <Td column="Email">{row.email}</Td>
                  <Td column="Edit">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon
                      className="editIcon"
                      onClick={() => this.showModal(row.id, row.email)}
                      icon={faEdit}
                    />
                  </Td>
                </Tr>
              );
            })}
          </Table>
          <EditUserModal
            permUpdated={this.state.permUpdated}
            permissionValue={this.state.permissionValue}
            emailCantBeBlank={this.state.emailCantBeBlank}
            userDataUpdated={this.state.userDataUpdated}
            handleChangePermissions={this.handleChangePermissions}
            passwordMatchFailure={this.state.passwordMatchFailure}
            handleDismiss={this.handleDismiss}
            show={this.state.showModal}
            close={this.closeModal}
            userId={this.state.rowId}
            email={this.state.selectedMail}
            handleChangePass={this.handleChangePass}
            handleChangePass2={this.handleChangePass2}
            handleChangeMail={this.handleChangeMail}
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share permissionsPrint value as I think same is object you are trying to render in the page

Comment: Could you log that permission print object

Comment: You cannot render object in the dom. You can render string in the dom. so you have to check, what is coming in the `permissionsPrint`. If you share the permissionsPrint value then i can help you

Comment: Add a unique `key` to each one of your `permissionsPrint` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se issue was that when the modal was closed, permUpdated state was kept as true, so I had to set it to false on close

```
closeModal() {
    console.log("CLOOOOOOSSSSINNGGGGGGGGGGGGG")
    this.setState({
        showModal: false,
        permUpdated: false
    }, () => {
        // console.log("clicked closeModal")
        // console.log(this.state.showModal)
    });
}
```

Comment: If you first fetch the data and on success response toggle the modal then you won't need `permUpdated` check.

Answer (score 2):

Here `{this.props.permUpdated ? {permissionsPrint} : null}` I don't think you need curly braces around `permissionsPrint` it should be :

```
  {this.props.permUpdated ? permissionsPrint : null}
```

`{permissionsPrint}` this is the same as `{permissionsPrint: permissionsPrint}` which is an Object with same key and value names, where value is a variable of the same name as of key name.

Comment: You are right, this  fixes the exception error, and now at least the page loads. But im still facing the issue of having do open the modal, then close it, and then reopen it to see my data updated

Comment: How does your `EditUserModal`'s toggle mechanism work? Could you share the complete code of modal.

Comment: I attached the whole stuff

Comment: is your modal toggling? if yes then are you having trouble showing the correct content in modal?

Comment: Exactly, it toggles properly, the issue is that. In order to show the correct data. I have to close the modal, then reopen it. If i dont do that it shows the data of the previously opened modal. Fe --> open modal1 --> see correct data--> open modal2 --> see modal1 data --> close modal 2 , open modal2 --> see modal 2 correct data

Comment: solved it, had to change permUpdated: false when closing the modal

Comment: Your code is a bit messy. Anyways after going through your code i think you are first toggling the modal and then fetching `permissionValue` which is not the correct way to do. First you should fetch the data and only when data has been returned by api the you should toggle the modal. Also i don't understand `this.props.permissionValue.map(e => (valuesData = Object.entries(e)));` this line. Why are you looping over permissionValue? also you are overriding `valuesData` within `map` I think it should be `valuesData.push(Object.entries(e))` otherwise you will get only one `checkbox input`.

Comment: Im toggling it before the fetch, because the toggling transfers an ID, which I need to send to the backend to select the data. Otherwise I wasnt able to get the id.(Or thats what I think) , and about using push instead of fetch, yes its a better approach. And im looping over permissionsValue to construct some html code in order to render it

Comment: on row click you can directly call `getPermissionsValue` passing down `row.id, row.email` and fetch the data once data is returned the in `setState` callback function toggle the modal.